# A simple question about a bijection in affine space.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, proof-explanation

Let $\mathbb{A}$ be a non empty set and $V$ be a vector space on a field $\mathbb{K}$

> **Definition 1.** An application $$f\colon\mathbb{A}\times\mathbb{A}\to V\quad (P,Q)\mapsto f(P,Q)$$
> defines an affine space structure on $\mathbb{A}$ if the following properties are true
>
> $(AF1)$ for all point $P$ of $\mathbb{A}$ and for all vector $\textbf{v}$ in $V$ exists a unique point $Q$ of $\mathbb{A}$ such that $f(P,Q)=\textbf{v}$;
>
> $(AF2)$ for every triad $(P,Q,S)$ of point of $\mathbb{A}$ we have $$f(P,Q)+f(Q,S)=f(P,S).$$

> **Definition 2.** A affine space on field $\mathbb{K}$ is a pair $$(\mathbb{A},f),$$ where $\mathbb{A}$ is a set, $V$ a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ and $f\colon\mathbb{A}\times\mathbb{A}\to V$ defines an affine space structure on $\mathbb{A}$, as in definition 1.

**Notation.** $f(P,Q)$ will be denoted by $$\textbf{PQ}\quad\text{or}\quad\textbf{Q}-\textbf{P}.$$

Let $(\mathbb{A},f)$ be an affine space over a field $\mathbb{K}$ and let $V$ be a finite vector space over the same field. We define the dimension of $\mathbb{A}$ as $$\dim\mathbb{A}=\dim V.$$

Consider a point $O\in\mathbb{A}$ and we consider the application $$g_O\colon V\to \mathbb{A},\quad \textbf{v}\mapsto O+\textbf{v}.$$

**Note.** From definition $\textbf{v}+O$ is that point $Q$ in $\mathbb{A}$ such that $\textbf{OQ}=\textbf{Q}-\textbf{O}=\textbf{v}$

> How can I prove that $g_O$ is a bijection?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does it mean for $g_O$ to be a bijection?

Comment: @DaveMeas to be injective and surjective

Comment: "for all point $P$
 of $\Bbb A$ and for all vector $\bf v$ in $V$ exists a unique point $Q$ of $\Bbb A$"

Comment: I should say I am giving a hint, not indicating something that needs correction or clarification.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I thought of prove injectivity in this way and for the surjectivity fixed $Q$ in $\mathbb{A}$ it suffices to take as vector of $V$ $(Q-O)$. It's correct? Or can everything be deduced from the axiom you pointed out and I can't see?

Comment: "for **all** $P$, ... exists a **unique** $Q$". The "all" requires $g_O$ to be surjective, the "unique" requires it to be injective. Though you need to consider $-\bf v$ to see it (an issue with the wording I hadn't originally noticed.)